# How to add a reference to Reference Assembly to a project

Tags: c#, msbuild

I have created a Solution with two projects of targeted to .NET Framework
1. Class library project ClassLibrary.csproj and outputs ClassLibrary.dll 
2. Console application project Console.csproj and outputs Console.exe

My class library project outputs a reference assembly in addition to a normal assembly.

How do I add reference assembly as a reference in Console application, so that while building Console application, reference assembly is used instead of implementation assembly of ClassLibrary

Comment: You mean you have the same dll project in your solution  and you are referring it

Comment: talking about Visual Studio?

Comment: It will probably not work with a <ProjectReference>, but you can always use a simple <Reference> (add by Browsing for the ref DLL).

Comment: Yes, its a same dll project in the same solution in Visual Studio